Scroll issue in the tree data view
Current behaviour.
Whenever I try to expand few rows in the tree data view, after some time there is very little space to scroll. Sometimes I am not able to expand the item for the below data. This is happening due to rows being pinned in the tree data view. I saw that every examples in ag-grid is having row pinned (parents row is pinned and child row is getting scrolled) when we scroll. Below is the scenario I am facing
Bug-Animation
enter image description here
Expected behaviour:
I want something like this
Expected behaviour
enter image description here
Below is the link for that
above animation
This above url is using the version "ag-grid-angular": "27.2.0",
Please tell us about your environment:
AG Grid version: 31.1.1
Browser: Google Chrome:121.0.6167.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)
I tried to look upon various examples of ag-grid (v31) for fixing this issue but I didn't find any. Below is the github link where I have raised this issue. Please take a look
ag-grid/issues/scroll-not-working
